# Is it possible to prove Cauchy integral formula by parametrizing the circle?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Theorem. Let $f$ be analytic everywhere inside and on a simple closed contour $C$, taken in the positive sense. If $z_0$ is any point interior to $C$, then $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}.$$

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Proof_sketch) starts with letting $C_r$ denote a positively oriented circle $|z-z_0|=r$, where $r$ is small enough that $C_r$ is interior to $C$. Since the function $f(z)/(z-z_0)$ is analytic between and on the contours $C$ and $C_r$, we have $$ \int_C \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0} = \int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}.$$

Can we then parametrize the contour $C_r$ and calculate $\int_{C_r} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}$? How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can proceed using [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals) and $r\to 0$:
\begin{align}
\int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(z_0+re^{i\theta})}{re^{i\theta}}re^{i\theta}i\,d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})\,d\theta=\\
&=[\text{Re}\,f(z_0+re^{ic_1})+i\text{Im}\,f(z_0+re^{ic_2})]2\pi i\to f(z_0)2\pi i.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\sum a_n (z-z_0)^{n}$ gives $\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta}) d\theta=\sum a_n \int_0^{2\pi}r^{n} e^{in\theta} d\theta=2 \pi a_0=2 \pi f(z_0)$ (since all but the first term vanish). Now $\int_{C_r} \frac {f(z)} {z-z_0} dz =i \int_0^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta}) d\theta=2\pi i f(z_0)$.